# What is /opt/sun_docs used for, in Solaris 10?

Tags: documentroot, solaris-10

Solaris 10, SPARC.

While trying clean up my "/opt" directory, I saw the "sun_docs" directory.

I scanned the contents with "du -a", and also found a single, possibly related file (/var/opt/sun_docs/sundocs.html).

If I understand correctly, it looks like a local set of HTML files, designed to be ready by a locally running browser? It looks like it could be shared via http, if an admin knew how to turn that on.

I did google and check docs.sun.com.

-ben

Answer (score 0):

That is not a directory that comes with the standard install of Solaris 10. 
It gets created if you install packages from the Solaris Documentation media. 
It is in no way system critical.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-0550/6mgbg7ec5/index.html

The files can be viewed through a local browser or could be moved into a location within a webserver's DocumentRoot to make them viewable over HTTP.